# Unresponsiveness with async event handlers in WPF in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5

I have created a simple async operation which is being kicked of when the button is clicked. Here is the whole code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        var htmlString = await DowloadPage("http://example.com");
        txtBlock1.Text = htmlString;
    }

    public async Task<string> DowloadPage(string uri) {

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {

            var htmlString = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
            return htmlString;   
        }
    }

}
```

Very easy. But when I click the button, I experience unresponsiveness on the UI thread. When I try to move around the window while the page is being downloaded, I am unable to.

Any idea what is going wrong?

*Edit:*

I tried with HttpClient in .NET 4.5 and it worked out pretty great as expected:

```
public async Task<string> DowloadPage(string uri) {

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var htmlString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return htmlString;   
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW there is a new [HttpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET 4.5 which is designed for `async`/`await`.

Comment: @dtb I am aware of that. Thanks but the issue here is different.

Comment: How long is `htmlString`?  It may simply take some time to render the `txtBlock1` with it.

Comment: @dtb do you think that newing up the `WebClient` would cause that blocking?

Comment: No, creating a `WebClient` instance is really lightweight. Have you checked how long `htmlString` is (see my comment above)?

Comment: @dtb I tried the same without putting the result to TextBlock. The result is the same.

Comment: Can you check if it happens with HttpClient as well?

Comment: @dtb can u confirm that it works as expected on your machine if possible?

Comment: @dtb see my edit to the question. HttpClient worked perfectly.

Comment: It looks like WebClient is doing some work on the UI thread then; I guess it's not really designed for use with `async`/`await`. Any reason you can't use HttpClient?

Comment: None, this is just a try out. I just wondered why it was happening.

Comment: File a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebClient` uses `HttpWebRequest`, which unfortunately [is not very asynchronous](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/9f75f92c-9a51-4921-bad5-97c2b15870bd), even if you use the "asynchronous" methods. It does a blocking DNS lookup, at least. It may also block during proxy negotiation and/or the initial HTTP connection.

An older release of `HttpClient` was just using a wrapper around `HttpWebRequest`. I [requested a truly-asynchronous `HttpClient`](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/267781), but never heard a response. The last time I checked `HttpClient`, it was still part of MVC; ASP.NET Web API wasn't around at that time, so they may have fixed `HttpClient` since then. *Or* the difference in behavior between `WebClient` and `HttpClient` on your machine may just have to do with DNS caches or some such.

Comment: Inside the download method (not the handler), should it ConfigureAwait(false) since its particular continuation doesn't need to be on the UI thread?  Obviously the handler shouldn't do so. :)

Comment: I would. It's best practice to do so, but (in this case) it won't cause any problems (like deadlocks) if he doesn't - it's just not as efficient as it could be.

Comment: I assume that since the questioner said HttpClient 'worked out great' that it was indeed 'fixed' to your liking?

Comment: I believe it has not been fixed. I examined it in dotPeek and the same call structure exists (`HttpClient` -> `HttpWebRequest` -> `ServicePoint` -> blocking DNS request).